# Scheduled method invoked before bean initialization

Tags: spring

I am using Spring scheduled annotation on one of my methods

```
@Inject
private Abcservice abcservice;

@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 300000)
private void abc(){
    abcservice.doSomething();
}
```

The problem I see sometimes is that, when I start the server, the bean `abcservice` is still null and the method is invoked resulting in `NullpointerException`. Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: This tutorial is pretty much doing the same as you are, maybe you can do it and see what it is you are doing wrong: http://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/

Comment: I saw the tutorial but the tutorial doesn't answer my question. Besides the tutorial is just to say how i can use @Scheduled functionality. It doesn't mention about my problem.

Comment: You could try adding `if (abservice != null)` before the call to `doSomething()` and see how that behaves.

Comment: Please give us a full reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

If anybody is interested, the problem disappears once the visibility of the method is set to be public.